# How to reference a vector value to a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to have a value stored in my vector, that same value that references the value of the key in the map and both have the same value.

```
std::vector<int> values;

std::map<std::string, int*> reference_value;
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int*>` -> `std::map<std::string, std::span<int>>`

Comment: What leads you to this approach. There are ways to make it work, but it feels brittle. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to perform any operation on the vector that may invalidate the vector's iterators (`insert`, `push_back`, `resize`, etc.), the example you posted won't work.

`std::vector` works by allocating a contiguous chunk of memory to store all your values. It may allocate space for a few extra values to avoid re-allocating on each insertion, but ultimately it will need to allocate a bigger chunk of memory to fit newly inserted values. Thus, it will move all the existing values into the newly allocated chunk of memory, and `free()/delete` the old one. This means, that addresses of all the values in the vector will change. After this, all pointers in your `unordered_map` would become invalid.

To workaround this, you may use a `std::shared_ptr` to hold a pointer to the underlying value. If the vector is reallocated, the `std::shared_ptr`s will be moved, but the addresses they hold will be unaffected.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> values;
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<int>> reference_value;
```

However, beware of the overhead of using a shared pointer.

Comment: the use of std::shared_ptr<int> could be used in map? , and this no longer requires using a pointer on the map? value.
I am trying to do this: append a 0 value to the vector and reference it the map.

Comment: Yes. `std::shared_ptr` can be used in a container like any other type. You would still be using a pointer in the map, but not a raw pointer (`int *`) but a shared pointer. Basically, both the vector and the map would be sharing a pointer to the same `int`, allocated somewhere on the heap (so not "owned" by any of the containers). The shared pointer will take care of deleting the integer when all references to it are destroyed (in other words, when the shared pointers are removed from both containers).